# Is there a way more simple, efficient or shorter for doing this?

Tags: python, list, input, append, list-comprehension

```
finallist = []
for each_time in range(10):
    x = int(input("Whats your number ? "))
    finallist.append(x)
```

It ask 10 times `"Whats your number ? "` and `.append` the obtained answer with `input()`as `int` into a list, i wanted to know it there are any simple way of doing this, with map maybe ? i've read on similar problems somethings about `json` too.

```
finallist.append(int(input("Whats your number ? ")))
```

I know i can do this, but for reasons of explanation, i preferred to write the first one.

Comment: `[int(input("What's your number? ")) for _ in range(11)]`?

Comment: This is *perfectly fine*. Prematurely optimizing is "the root of all evil". Doing it for the sake of saving a couple of lines is just folly.

Comment: Thanks, i was just wondering if a simpler built-in would do this for me @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* do it with a list comprehension:

```
finallist = [int(input("Whats your number ? ")) for _ in range(10)]
```

but I [**wouldn't recommend doing it**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/404556), since it's less clear what's going on.

Or, as Zen of Python would say:

```
>>> import this
...
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

List comprehensions (and `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc.) are best when your function has no side-effects. And asking user for input has side-effects.

Comment: up-voted for recommending the OP against using this. The OP really isn't gaining that much by using a list comprehension vs a vanilla loop. As @juanpa.arrivillaga said in his comment, premature optimization is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: It depends on your perspective of whether determining the user's input is a "side effect" or a computation. It isn't "fire the nukes" for i in 1 to 10, it's "determine i'th entered entered number" for i in 1 to 10.

Comment: Either way, you're tainting a pure list comprehension with a computation.

Comment: The point of a list comprehension is to compute a list of things. What do you use list comprehensions for?

Comment: I like to use list comprehensions only on pure functions. That way I know I'll always get the same result (list) for the same input -- input being some sequence I'm iterating, not a user.

Comment: Well, actually i was wondering if my way was slower then other existing ways

Comment: @BrunoCerk, remember that ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29). :) Regardless, the slowest part will probably be the user input part, not your loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a comprehension:

```
numbers = [int(input("Number please")) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Minor improvement: If you never use the variable that you use to iterate over an iterable - `i` in your case - it is common convention to use `_` instead. That let's the reader know that you're only iterating over the iterable for code repetition.

Comment: @ChristianDean didn't knew that, thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

Use comprehension is always a better alternative to a `for` loop:

```
finallist = [int(input("Whats your number ? ")) for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
while not len(result) == 10:
    result += [input('What is your number? ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider allowing the user to type all of them in a once separated by spaces, something along these lines:

```
while True:
    s = input("Enter 10 numbers (separated by spaces)? ").split()
    if len(s) != 10:
        print("Sorry, that was {} values, try again".format(len(s)))
    else:
        finallist = [int(n) for n in s]
        break
```